# Asking the same question

Tags: discussion

So I noticed a user that created a question yesterday.

He/she got no answer for it.

Today I noticed the exact same question popped up again.

I check and yesterday's question was deleted.

Is that allowed to do that? Posting the same question on consecutive days by removing the same oldest question.

It feels kind of spammy to me to always be in the recent/active questions list (similar to editing questions to make it go back up to the active list)

NB: I already flagged the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general is not OK.
It's indeed spamming.
But if you see this behavior once, leave a comment explaining why this is wrong.
If you tried the "education" approach once and you see no improvement and the user has the same behavior, flag the questions.

Comment: Done thanks for that

Comment: Users should be encouraged to use the bounty system instead of deleting and re-asking a new question